# install barnyard2 ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, snort

I trying to install barnyard2 in ubuntu 12.04 32-bit

I'm configure using syntax:

> ./configure --with-mysql-libraries=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

and when I trying to compile daq-1.1.1 using a makefile, I encountered the following errors:

> make[3]: Leaving directory `/root/snortinstall/barnyard2/src'
>   make[2]: Leaving directory`/root/snortinstall/barnyard2/src'
>   Making all in etc
>   make[2]: Entering directory `/root/snortinstall/barnyard2/etc'
>   make[2]: Nothing to be done for`all'. make[2]: Leaving directory
>   `/root/snortinstall/barnyard2/etc' Making all in doc make[2]: Entering
>   directory`/root/snortinstall/barnyard2/doc' make[2]: Nothing to be
>   done for `all'. make[2]: Leaving directory`
>   /root/snortinstall/barnyard2/doc' Making all in rpm make[2]: Entering
>   directory `/root/snortinstall/barnyard2/rpm' make[2]: Nothing to be
>   done for`all'. make[2]: Leaving directory
>   `/root/snortinstall/barnyard2/rpm' Making all in schemas make[2]:
>   Entering directory`/root/snortinstall/barnyard2/schemas' make[2]:
>   Nothing to be done for `all'. make[2]: Leaving directory`
>   /root/snortinstall/barnyard2/schemas' Making all in m4 make[2]:
>   Entering directory `/root/snortinstall/barnyard2/m4' make[2]: Nothing
>   to be done for`all'. make[2]: Leaving directory
>   `/root/snortinstall/barnyard2/m4' make[2]: Entering directory`
>   /root/snortinstall/barnyard2' make[2]: Nothing to be done for
>   `all-am'. make[2]: Leaving directory`/root/snortinstall/barnyard2'
>   make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/snortinstall/barnyard2'

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
sudo ./configure --with-mysql --with-mysql-libraries=/usr/lib
```

or

```
sudo ./configure --with-mysql --with-mysql-libraries=/usr/lib32
```

for me it worked with

```
sudo ./configure --with-mysql --with-mysql-libraries=/usr/lib64
```

but I am useing ubuntu 12.04 64bit