# Unable to run configure for barnyard2

Tags: linux, snort

I used this tutorial on how to [install and configure Snort](http://www.symmetrixtech.com/articles/016-snortinstallguide2953.pdf,)

however, I'm stuck while trying to install Barnyard 2. I was able to download and unzip it, but when I tried to configure it using `./configure--with-mysql --with-mysql-libraries=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu` I received; `./configure: command not found` message.

I even tried the suggestions given [in this topic:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429876/install-barnyard2-ubuntu-12-04)

but I received the same results. I even re-downloaded Barnyard2, but it keeps on giving me the same error message. Any suggestions on what I did wrong?

Oh, I'm using Linux Mint, if that'll help.

Update: I've checked, and there is a configure file in the folder, but to be safe, I downloaded it again, and when I executed this command:

`autoreconf -fvi -I ./m4`

I received the error message:

`autoreconf: Entering directory`.'
autoreconf: configure.in: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal -I ./m4 -I m4 --output=aclocal.m4t
Can't exec "aclocal": No such file or directory at /usr/share/autoconf/Autom4te/FileUtils.pm line 326.
autoreconf: failed to run aclocal: No such file or directory``

And I also looked at the properties of the configure file, just to be safe:

`ls -l | grep configure`

`-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  34166 Mei  27  2013 configure.in`

And even after changing it to executable:

`-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  34166 Mei  27  2013 configure.in`

I'm still getting the same error message.

Comment: Make sure you have configure file in source package

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

First, I had to install automake.

Next, after installing automake, I had to change the configure file from configure.in to configure.ac

Once I did that, everything went smoothly.